# Kubuntu 14.10 freezes when connecting to wifi - Netgear wg311v3

Tags: wireless, drivers, kubuntu, ndiswrapper

I have an old Dell Desktop that I am finally getting around to replacing Windows on it.  The current location for the desktop has no wired location.  I have an old Netgear wg311v3 card and have jumped through various drivers etc with ndiswrapper.

I am using the 64-bit version of the driver from the actual manufactuer (German company) that I found through askubuntu.  Wireless is now showing up so super excited on that...

However whenever I try to actually connect to the wifi network the whole machine freezes and stops responding.  I have to hit the power button to turn things off.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Note I followed: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Device/Netgear_WG311_v3 which while a bit out of date I thought was useful.  Most guides still link back to this page.  Also followed: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=320111

Additional notes:
1.  Upon powering on device after the freeze I need to execute a sudo modprobe ndiswrapper before wireless shows up as available each time.  Something isn't being written to the system correctly

2. Output that was requested: 
     jonathan@HomePC:~$ sudo ndiswrapper -l
       mrv8335x64 : driver installed
               device (11AB:1FAA) present
3. Additional output that was requested: 03:01.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88w8335 [Libertas] 802.11b/g Wireless [11ab:1faa] (rev 03)
4. Output from last command: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9685285/

Comment: Please edit your question to add the results of these terminal commands: lspci -nn | grep 0280 and also: ndiswrapper -l Thanks.

Comment: Don' know if this helps out as well, but I'm also seeing this: jonathan@HomePC:~$ dmesg | grep ndiswrapper
[  319.106992] ndiswrapper: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
[  319.108782] ndiswrapper version 1.59 loaded (smp=yes, preempt=no)
[  319.217209] ndiswrapper: driver mrv8335x64 (Marvell,07/01/2005,3.2.0.7) loaded

Comment: Please also show: cat /var/log/syslog | grep ndis | tail -n20. As the output will be lengthy, paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com. So far, we see nothing wrong with ndiswrapper.

Comment: Ok did some googling and cam across this to connect via the command line to see what happened
nmcli d wifi connect WiFiSSID password WiFiPassword iface wlan0

I needed to execute this as sudo

I received this error message on the console: .c:3101: signal id '16' is invalid for instance '0x701b90'

Comment: I have never seen this before. I'd love to see the syslog I requested above.

Comment: @chili555 thanks for helping out so much, the syslog is the last item #4  http://paste.ubuntu.com/9685285/

Comment: this is a fresh build of Kubuntu 14.10 x64 version.  I'm using the 64bit drivers from Maravell or whatever the manufacturer is

Comment: I don't know if this is an answer but the problem has been solved by creating a less secure wireless network.  The system is setup on a "guest network" with no security password or anything.  No issues since creating a separate network for the system.  Not the best solution but at least it works.